# using openssl s_client for renegotiation with different ciphers

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, openssl, tls1.2

I am testing SSL, my use case is if the client wants to do a Renegotiation but propose different set of ciphers this time, is there a way this could be tested with openssl s_client. I know R will send a Reneg request, but how do I include Ciphers also?

Comment: This cannot be done with `s_client`.

Comment: Any other alternative?

Comment: No, I don't know alternatives. But the use case looks very strange for me. Why would you want to offer different ciphers inside a renegotiation?